# Understanding ON conditions in SQL JOINS

Tags: sql

The following is a question from my SQL textbook:

> The HR department wants to determine the names of all employees who
>   were hired after Davies. Create a query to display the name and hire
>   date of any employee hired after employee Davies.

The solution given in the textbook is:

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.hire_date 
FROM employees e 
JOIN employees davies ON (davies.last_name = 'Davies') 
WHERE davies.hire_date < e.hire_date;
```

I don't understand the ON condition (`davies.last_name = 'Davies'`). Can someone please explain to me what it does and how it helps solve the question.

Comment: It would help to know what the tables in your textbook look like...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to make it a bit broader. I also changed your tag from `sqlplus` to `sql` as that will get the question seen by more people. Finally I've indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't find `join`s with constant conditions to be that simple to follow.  I would write this logic using a scalar subquery:

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.hire_date 
FROM employees e 
WHERE e.hire_date > (SELECT davies.hire_date FROM employees davies WHERE davies.last_name = 'Davies');
```

I think this is a more direct translation of the question.  And you can readily see what it is doing.  The subquery is getting the hire date for Davies.  The outer query is comparing them.

This is subtly different from the `JOIN` version.  This version will generate an error if the data has two "Davies".  The `JOIN` version will generate a strange set of rows with duplicates, probably including one of the Davies.  I find the error to be more in the spirit of the example.

If I were to use `JOIN`s, I would start with a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.hire_date 
FROM employees e CROSS JOIN
     employees davies 
WHERE davies.last_name = 'Davies' AND
      davies.hire_date < e.hire_date;
```

This looks more "natural".  Normally filtering conditions on a single table are in the `WHERE` clause (although once you learn about outer joins, this will change).  I cannot think of a situation where I put filtering conditions on one table in the `ON` and then comparisons *between* tables in the `WHERE`.  It is allowed, but looks awkward to me.

If I were to present this as a single `JOIN`, I would put *both* conditions in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT e.last_name, e.hire_date 
FROM employees e JOIN
     employees davies 
     ON davies.last_name = 'Davies' AND
        davies.hire_date < e.hire_date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just a quick question...What is your experience level when it comes to sql (education and so on)?. Also, how do you get good at using it? It seems challenging, but also interesting.

Comment: @Anthony . . . I've been using SQL, writing database engines, and writing database software since 1989.  One of my books, "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel", is specifically devoted to using SQL as a querying tool.

Comment: Ok. How do you improve?

Comment: Agree the scalar subquery is what most coders would choose but the range variables `e` and `davies` serve no purpose and should be dropped. The second query looks most unnatural to me: yes range variables must be used here but you have disconnected the range variable name `davies` from the predicate; I prefer the OP's to your second (but your first is best IMO).

Answer (score 1):

This type of join is called self join where a table is joined with itself. In the above example, the ON condition is used to filter the employees table with alias `davies`. After filtering, `davies` table will have all rows where the `employees.last_name` is `Davies`. Once you have all such rows, the where condition is comparing the `hire_date` of `davies` table with all the employees in the original table and getting the `last_name` and `hire_date` of people who were hired after `Davies`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still don't understand something. Wouldn't there only be one row in the Davies table where davies.last_name = 'Davies'

Comment: The number of rows with the value `davies.last_name = 'Davies` doesn't matter. What you need to understand is self join is a way to compare value in a cell with other cells in the same table (`hire_date` of Davies with `hire_date` of other employees in this case). That's what the author is trying to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

in condition davies is alias name of employee table(second table - after join)
so its means :
check last_name in joined table(davies table , field last name ) equals word "Davies"